# Cleaning data based on time series and change values not within certain interval to NA in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to compute a trial to trial change of values and then delete those changes that are outside a certain interval. My data is below.

Here is what I have tried

```
 df_all_UK2  %>%
  group_by(ID, trial) %>% 
  filter(phase_bins == "baseline") %>% 
  mutate(drop = case_when(sum(is.na(nosetip))= 3 ~ TRUE,
                            TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>% 
  select(drop=="FALSE")
```

This should drop all trials from IDs that have no usable `baseline` value for that `trial` (A non-usable trial has all three values as `NA`s in `phase_bins = baseline`
But I can't get it to work.

After that, I need a difference measure (`diff`) of change in `nosetip` to the previous trial and to delete all trials not within the right interval.

```
# for the difference it is crucial that stimuli are in right order
df_all_UK2$time <- factor(df_all_UK$time , levels=c("pre_60", "pre_30","pre", "base1" , "base2" ,"stim1" ,"stim2" , "stim3" , "stim4" , "stim5",  "stim6",  "stim7" , "stim8",  "stim9", "stim10" ,"stim11", "stim12" ,"rec1",   "rec2",   "rec3" ,  "rec4"  ,"rec5",   "rec6",   "bre1"  , "bre2" ,  "bre3" ,  "bre4"  , "bre5" ))


# then compute difference
df_all_UK2 <- df_all_UK2  %>%
  group_by(ID, trial) %>% 
  arrange(ID, cond_f, time) %>% 
  mutate(diff=nosetip-lag(nosetip,default=NA, n=1L))
```

This step works, but then filtering out the ones that are too high or too low, does not.

```
# set values to NA if difference to value before exceeds is not between -0.5 and 0.5
df_all_UK2 %>% 
  mutate(nosetip = case_when(diff < -0.5 ~ NA, 
                             diff > 0.5 ~ NA, 
                             TRUE ~ nosetip))
```

Any ideas on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated!!

This is my data:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("UK103", "UK104", "UK105", "UK106", "UK107", 
"UK108", "UK110", "UK111", "UK112", "UK113", "UK114", "UK115", 
"UK116", "UK117", "UK119", "UK122", "UK123", "UK126", "UK130", 
"UK132", "UK135", "UK136", "UK138", "UK139", "UK140", "UK147", 
"UK148", "UK150", "UK153", "UK155", "UK159", "UK160", "UK162", 
"UK163", "UK164", "UK101", "UK102", "UK109", "UK118", "UK120", 
"UK121", "UK124", "UK125", "UK127", "UK128", "UK129", "UK131", 
"UK133", "UK134", "UK137", "UK141", "UK142", "UK143", "UK144", 
"UK145", "UK146", "UK149", "UK151", "UK152", "UK154", "UK156", 
"UK157", "UK158", "UK161", "UK166", "UK167", "UK168", "UK169", 
"UKA102", "UKA103", "UKA104", "UKA105", "UKA106", "UKA107", "UKA108", 
"UKA109", "UKA110", "UKA111", "UKA112", "UKA113", "UKA114", "UKA115", 
"UKA116", "UKA117", "UKA119", "UKA120", "UKA121", "UKA122", "UKA101", 
"UKA118"), class = "factor"), cond_f = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("artificial", "babble", 
"cry", "laugh"), class = "factor"), trial = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"
), class = "factor"), time = structure(3:12, .Label = c("pre_60", 
"pre_30", "pre", "base1", "base2", "stim1", "stim2", "stim3", 
"stim4", "stim5", "stim6", "stim7", "stim8", "stim9", "stim10", 
"stim11", "stim12", "rec1", "rec2", "rec3", "rec4", "rec5", "rec6", 
"bre1", "bre2", "bre3", "bre4", "bre5"), class = "factor"), nosetip = c(29.4, 
29.1, 29.6, 29, 29.1, 29.2, 29.3, NA, NA, NA), phase_bins = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("pre", "baseline", 
"stim_bin1", "stim_bin2", "recovery", "break"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), groups = structure(list(ID = structure(1L, .Label = c("UK103", 
"UK104", "UK105", "UK106", "UK107", "UK108", "UK110", "UK111", 
"UK112", "UK113", "UK114", "UK115", "UK116", "UK117", "UK119", 
"UK122", "UK123", "UK126", "UK130", "UK132", "UK135", "UK136", 
"UK138", "UK139", "UK140", "UK147", "UK148", "UK150", "UK153", 
"UK155", "UK159", "UK160", "UK162", "UK163", "UK164", "UK101", 
"UK102", "UK109", "UK118", "UK120", "UK121", "UK124", "UK125", 
"UK127", "UK128", "UK129", "UK131", "UK133", "UK134", "UK137", 
"UK141", "UK142", "UK143", "UK144", "UK145", "UK146", "UK149", 
"UK151", "UK152", "UK154", "UK156", "UK157", "UK158", "UK161", 
"UK166", "UK167", "UK168", "UK169", "UKA102", "UKA103", "UKA104", 
"UKA105", "UKA106", "UKA107", "UKA108", "UKA109", "UKA110", "UKA111", 
"UKA112", "UKA113", "UKA114", "UKA115", "UKA116", "UKA117", "UKA119", 
"UKA120", "UKA121", "UKA122", "UKA101", "UKA118"), class = "factor"), 
    trial = structure(2L, .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: For the second issue, you say you want to filter out the ones that are too high or low. Could you just use ```filter(diff < 0.5 | diff > 0.5)```?

Comment: Oh dear, it alsways looks so easy when you know how to do it! thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a little more time so I thought I would give you an actual answer. I will preface this by saying I'm confident there is a more succinct and simpler way to filter when you have the three NA baseline values, but this is probably how I'd do it.

I wanted the dataset a little bigger than the one you shared, just to make sure I was filtering the right thing, so I made my own called `dat`. What I did, I made a second dataframe called `dat_drop` where I included only the `phase_bins == "baseline`. Then I summarized the missing values, and kept only those those ID's and trials that had three NAs.

From here, I made `dat2` by filtering `dat`, removing any IDs that were in the `dat_drop$ID` column AND the trial was in `dat_drop$trial`. Thus, it should keep only those IDs and trials that were not missing three baseline. Depending on your whole dataframe though, I can see this not working (i.e. for some id and trials you have only two baseline rows, and both are NA).

After this, I used your code to create the diff column for `dat3`. I also included my comment for `dat3()`, where I used `filter(diff < 0.5 | diff > 0.5)`. I realized this is a delayed answer, and it's probably not the most efficient or robust, but hopefully this is helpful. Or maybe it will prompt someone to give an even better solution!

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
dat<-data.frame("ID" = c(rep("UK103", 10), rep("UK104", 10), rep("UK105",10), rep("UK106", 10)), 
                 "cond_f" = rep("cry", 40),
                 "trial" = rep(2, 40),
                 "time" = rep(c("pre", "base1", "base2", "stim1", "stim2", "stim3", "stim4", "stim5", "stim6", "stim7"),4),
                 "nosetip" = c(rnorm(7, 29), NA, NA, NA, rnorm(10, 29), NA, NA, NA, rnorm(7, 29), NA, rnorm(8, 29), NA),
                 "phase_bins" = rep(c(rep("baseline", 3), rep("stim_bin1", 6), "stim_bin2"), 4))

dat_drop<-dat%>%
  filter(phase_bins == "baseline")%>%
  group_by(ID, trial) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(is.na(nosetip)), .groups = "drop")%>%
  filter(n == 3)

dat2<-dat%>%
  filter(!(ID == dat_drop$ID & trial == dat_drop$trial))

dat3<-dat2%>%
  group_by(ID, trial) %>% 
  arrange(ID, cond_f, time) %>% 
  mutate(diff=nosetip-lag(nosetip,default=NA, n=1L))%>%
  ungroup()

dat3 %>% 
  filter(diff < 0.5 | diff > 0.5)
```

Comment: Only just saw this! Thank you so much for your answer!